# How many times a single transaction can be included into different blocks?

Tags: confirmations, block-validity

I would like  to know is there a limit after which a miner cannot include a transaction into his block.

Answer (score 3):

Each transaction can only be included into one block since it spends the coins (outputs) of the origin address. Including it in a second block would be invalid because the coins are already spent.

Comment: it says that in order to see that your transaction is definitely validated, i'ts a good practice to wait for 6 confirmations. Something is obscure at this level. Does that mean that you have to wait for 6 blocks to be added to the blockchain.

Comment: Yes transaction is only included in one block. This is 1 confirmation. All miners then use this block hash in their next block header. Next block mined makes confirmation count 2 and that's how number of confirmations keep increasing for a transaction but it was included only in one block.

Comment: This transaction was included in block 666206: https://blockstream.info/tx/4358c3454d1ffed6b3839270d1b964f16b93cd6f20426e91bb6cb26fe8fa9612 had 1 confirmation while writing this comment. Confirmations will keep increasing as we see more blocks mined.

Comment: Since a later block can only be valid if all content of all prior blocks was valid, each block makes a transaction harder to change. Therefore, we count additional blocks as additional "confirmations" of events included in prior blocks.